# Check if Combo box is empty C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am trying to check if a combo box is empty using C# in a Windows Application Form. Below are two possible ways:

1. if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox1.Text))
2. if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)

In order to ensure that the user would **ONLY** select a value from the drop down and **NOT** write it s own answer, which is the best approach?
From my research the second method (if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)) will satisfy my needs. Am l right?

Comment: If dropdown lits has *empty string* as an option the 1st possibility is wrong (user can deliberatly choose the empty option). In case of 2nd option I'd rather put it as `if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex < 0)` in order not to use *magic constant* `-1`

Answer (score 2):

If your concern is only making sure that users choose an item from the list available, simply change your combobox's `DropDownStyle` to `DropDownList`

or if you want to allow them to type but then ensure it is on the list, you can do something like this:

```
var txt = comboBox1.Text;

if(string.IsNullOrEmpty())
  return;

var test = comboBox1.Items?.OfType<string>().ToList().Any(x => x?.Trim() == txt?.Trim());
```

so if test is false, it means what they have selected/typed does not exist in list of available items

Answer (score 0):

for combobox you can use this code below to check if it's empty or not

```
 if(comboBox1.Items.Count == 0 )
 {
    // your code
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i try and it 's work. Feel free to comment:

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1 )
```